# ActiveRecord, select query for an Array returns ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ImportsController#index

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, smart-listing

I have a custom list that i create from the "backoffice" where i add the columns i want to retrieve from the DB table. This becomes an array. Well, i want to retrieve just that columns from the rows that match an Id.

This is my code:

```
def load_import_contacts
    @import_contacts_column_filter = current_user.current_organization.import_columns.split(/,/) # the "custom filter" that retrieve columns
    @import_contacts = UserImport.select(@import_contacts_column_filter).where(organization_id: current_user.current_organization.id) # the query
    # here all ok, objects filtered how i want.
    @import_contacts_listing = smart_listing_create(
      # here comes the error message
      :import_contacts,
      @import_contacts,
      partial: 'contacts/listing_import',
      default_sort: {created_at: "desc"}
    )
  end
```

The error message:

**Title**

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ImportsController#index
```

**Body message**

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' name, surname1, surname2, phone, adress, city, zipcode, zone, birthdate, firstv' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(reference_number, name, surname1, surname2, phone, adress, city, zipcode, zone, birthdate, firstvisit, mutua, organization_id) FROM `user_imports` WHERE `user_imports`.`organization_id` = 279
```

More details

```
Extracted source (around line #15):
```

Line 15:

```
@import_contacts_listing = smart_listing_create(
```

Comment: Is requesting one count on multiple columns valid? I think not. I think there should be `count()` seperately for each field...

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(reference_number, name, surname1, surname2, phone, adress, city, zipcode, zone, birthdate, firstvisit, mutua, organization_id)`. Is this valid sql syntax? I think not.

Comment: I mean that you either select count of all fields, `count(*)` or one field `count(id)`, but you can't select `count(field1, field2, ...)`, unless I am very much mistaken...

Comment: i cannot select an array of fields?

Comment: if i add 
`@import_contacts.each do |before|
      puts before.name
 end`
The action continue rendering the template.

Comment: so strange @RubyRacer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137280/discussion-between-marcos-r-guevara-and-ruby-racer).

Answer (score 0):

**Strange solution**:

When i add this line before smart listing

```
**@import_contacts.each do |before|
end**
```

All runs ok, it's strange, i don't know why this happens.